# Count where timestamp in another table is less/more than interval from main table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count users that's not posting any transaction in one month / year

But transaction has many entries for one user, this is the rough example:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
|       3 |
+---------+
+----------------+---------+---------------------+
| transaction_id | user_id |      recorded       |
+----------------+---------+---------------------+
| t1             |       1 | 2019-01-01 hh:mm:yy |
| t2             |       1 | 2019-01-02 hh:mm:yy |
| t3             |       2 | 2018-01-01 hh:mm:yy |
| t4             |       2 | 2018-01-02 hh:mm:yy |
| t5             |       2 | 2018-01-02 hh:mm:yy |
| t6             |       3 | 2018-01-03 hh:mm:yy |
+----------------+---------+---------------------+
```

How can I get the count of users that's not adding any transaction in above `2018-01-03`?

Comment: Q1: Is there a specific period from date to date? Q2: is day part not needed?

Comment: @AdamNorman Q1 : yes please, but as for now, only one condition needed, feel free to answer more. Q2 : day part?

Comment: I.e you need yyyy- mm only dd is not important is it?

Comment: In real world, yes, only yyyy-mm is needed, but after seeing your answer, is that long just to filter out user that's not adding transaction in range?
Sry, I'm new to sql.

Comment: You can change this piece of code with your first table SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM            yourtable

Comment: And make sure that date part will really return YYYY for year and MM for month. All just you need is to run the procedure piece after piece to figure out the solutions or to modify it to meet your suitable solution

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Creating temp table that stores YYYYMM as int
declare @DateTo datetime =GetDate()
declare @DateFrom datetime= DATEADD(Year, -2, GetDate())
create Table #DateScope1(AllDates int )
-- loop to fill the temp table to fill it with date range of YYYYMM
while @DateFrom<@DateTo
begin
insert into #DateScope1(AllDates) 
select convert(nvarchar(4), DatePart(Year, @DateFrom))+right('00'+convert(nvarchar(2),DatePart(Month, @DateFrom)),2)
set @DateFrom=DATEADD(Month, 1, @DateFrom)
end


-- 1- Get All Distinct users
-- 2- cross join with the temp table to get all users with all months
-- 3- Get Distinct users again but now with their YYYYMM Months
-- 4- Now make left outer join with 2 and 3 then filter with 3 dates nulls
SELECT          AllXAll.user_id, AllDates
FROM            (SELECT        tUsers.user_id, [#DateScope1].AllDates
                          FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
                                                    FROM            yourtable) AS tUsers CROSS JOIN
                                                    [#DateScope1]) AS AllXAll LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        user_id, recorded
                               FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, CONVERT(nvarchar(4), DATEPART(Year, recorded)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(nvarchar(2), DATEPART(Month, recorded)), 2) AS recorded
                                                         FROM            (SELECT        user_id, recorded
                                                                                   FROM            yourtable AS yourtable_1) AS t1_1) AS t1_2) AS t1 ON AllXAll.user_id = t1.user_id AND AllXAll.AllDates = t1.recorded 
where recorded is null

drop table #DateScope1
```